# Error while converting from .pb to .tflite on windows

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I have a frozen tensorflow object detection model `frozen_inference_graph.pb` and I need to convert it in `.tflite` format to use it in an android app.

I am using `tflite_convert` as suggested here, https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tensorflow-for-poets-2-tflite/#2

```
tflite_convert 
--graph_def_file=frozen_inference_graph.pb 
--output_file=new_graph.tflite 
--input_format=TENSORFLOW_GRAPHDEF 
--output_format=TFLITE 
--input_shape=1,224,224,3 
--input_array=image_tensor 
--output_array=detection_boxes,detection_scores,detection_classes,num_detections 
--inference_type=FLOAT 
--input_data_type=FLOAT
```

This is the error that I'm getting:

```
Check failed: array.data_type == array.final_data_type Array "image_tensor" 
has mis-matching actual and final data types (data_type=uint8, final_data_type=float).
Fatal Python error: Aborted
```

Edit: I read the tflite docs and it was mentioned that, only models frozen using `freeze.py` can be converted using `tflite_convert`. But I used `export_inference_graph.py` to get `frozen_inference_graph.pb`. 
Is there any other way to convert an object detection model to `tflite`. I am using the model `ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco_11_06_2017`.

Answer (score 1):

The convertor can change input and/or output types, but only one side: if the model has float input tensor, you can create a tflite model with `quantized (uint8) input`, but not vice versa.

Remove `--input_data_type=FLOAT` from your command, and it should work.

Comment: I did as you suggested but it still gives me the same error.Then, I used `inference_input_type=QUANTIZED_UINT8` instead of `input_data_type=FLOAT`  and it seemed to work fine until I got `Some of the operators in the model are not supported by the standard TensorFlow Lite runtime.`

Comment: Adding non-standard operators to tflite is not a trivial task.

Comment: @KishoreKumarSingh, I don't see `input_data_type` as parameter and `inference_input_type` looks like an attribute (https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1/lite/TFLiteConverter#attributes). How was you able to feed these two parameters?

Comment: @CloudCho I believe these parameters were relevant for an [older version](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/lite/g3doc/r1/convert/cmdline_reference.md) of the command-line tool.

Comment: @AlexCohn, thanks for the information. Regarding you comment about non standard tensor operation addition, I found `converter.allow_custom_ops = True` (ref: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/35590#issuecomment-635711905). Would this command be a solution or temporary band aid?